# ng-click is not working in mobile screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup, angularjs-ng-click

I have a pop-up in my web version of the application which works fine.

```
<a href="" ng-click="backToCareTemp()"> <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> <span>Back</span></a>
```

When I reduce the screen resolution for mobile screen, the pop-up back button won't work. The text is displayed but unable to click it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with the CSS and it fixed.

Sorry not an Angular question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ngTouch. According to Angular Documentation.

> A more powerful replacement for the default ngClick designed to be
>   used on touchscreen devices. Most mobile browsers wait about 300ms
>   after a tap-and-release before sending the click event. This version
>   handles them immediately, and then prevents the following click event
>   from propagating.
>
> Requires the ngTouch module to be installed.